# Install custom plugin on Google Ghrome Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, google-chrome, ubuntu

I've got a problem while trying to install rutoken plugin for Google Chrome v. 40.0.2214.115 (64-bit) on Ubuntu 14.04.

That's what I try:

1. Download plugin from http://www.rutoken.ru/support/download/rutoken-plugin/ and unpack files, so I had librtpkcs11ecp.so, npCryptoPlugin.so files.
2. Create a directory for plugins, in the Google Chrome's installation directory.

`sudo mkdir /opt/google/chrome/plugins`

3. Copy *.so files to the plugins directory.

Then I've restarted Chrome:

`google-chrome -–enable-plugins`

The problem is that when I run `chrome://plugins/` there is no such plugin in a list.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Java JRE is not more working on Chrome

https://askubuntu.com/a/590181

> NPAPI support by Chrome
>
> The Java plug-in for web browsers relies on the cross platform plugin architecture NPAPI, which has long been, and currently is, supported by all major web browsers. Google announced in September 2013 plans to remove NPAPI support from Chrome by "the end of 2014", thus effectively dropping support for Silverlight, Java, Facebook Video and other similar NPAPI based plugins. Recently, Google has revised their plans and now state that they plan to completely remove NPAPI by late 2015. As it is unclear if these dates will be further extended or not, we strongly recommend Java users consider alternatives to Chrome as soon as possible. Instead, we recommend Firefox, Internet Explorer and Safari as longer-term options.

Answer (score 0):

I installed plugin updated but I face issue at testing time plugin not work properly in Chrome using link http://java.com/en/download/installed8.jsp?detect=jre If you got message "This plug-in is not supported" then follow following steps: 
In your URL bar, enter:

1. chrome://flags/#enable-npapi
2. Click the Enable link for the Enable NPAPI configuration option.
3. Click the Relaunch button that now appears at the bottom of the
   configuration page.

and test it again using http://java.com/en/download/installed8.jsp?detect=jre link.